# Suitable Javascript framework for ASP.NET MVC with razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

I have been struggling a lot finding a suitable JavaScript framework for ASP .NET MVC and razor.

I have implemented a simple demo application with Angular 2, Aurelia and AngularJS.

After my experience i find that Angular 2 and Aurelia can integrate with MVC and razor but they are not built for MVC and razor. They are built for Single Page Applications.

However the old AngularJS seems to integrate way better - but i fear it is being deprecated by the new frameworks.

I am not that experienced with client side programming and i find the modern way(NPM ,Bundling, Transpiling, linting and so on) a bit confusing since there is so many different frameworks to choose from.

So my question: Does anyone have experience with JavaScript frameworks that integrates well with MVC and razor?

Thanks :)

Comment: KnockoutJS/React as they only provide the view part of mvc

Comment: When you say JS frameworks, what kind of frameworks are you expecting? Because Angulars are One page app MVCs.

Comment: _However the old AngularJS seems to integrate way better_ but it's the main usage is for a SPA as well, anyway, it depends on what you want to do, for some using jQuery or just normal JavaScript is enough.

Comment: Also I believe this question does not belong here as it is not related to codes. Maybe some other community?

Comment: @Sagar I flagged it as too broad but I guess it could fall under the flag "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" as well.

Comment: @George Never used flags before. And I don't see the option of too broad or recommendations either

Comment: @Sagar The options on the first pop up that end with ellipses will show you the reason after you've selected it, so when you select "should be closed" it'll come up with more options to choose from.

Comment: @George, you have a good point. Maybe a framework not needed - it depends. Alexander Derck, i have seen some knockoutjs code and yes it seems quite simple and integratable- not taking control of mvc. I will take a look at React. Thanks. I think the post is quite relevant for many but i can see that you guys dont agree on that :)

Comment: I think it’s quite a useful question and brings up useful discussion on an issue that some of us face but hard to  find answers for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use KnockoutJS. It helps you to create rich, responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying data model.

knockout.js helps you simplify dynamic JavaScript UIs using the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern. It also has a complementary project KnockoutMVC to bind with MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i don't know about KnockoutMVC but i will take a look at it - sounds promising. I think i will take a deeper look into knockoutJS.

Comment: If you are afraid that Angular is being deprecated - knockoutJS is way older and less active than Angular. I would watch out as support is going to be limited going forward